# Reloading page on modal close in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Questions from an angularjs newbie.

This is a two part problem.

I have a page which has a drop down (populated using web service), a text box and button 'Go'. Button ng-click causes the value of drop down and text box to hit a web service which returns JSON which I use to display the grid (Id, name). Grid also has delete button for each row. All this is inside one controller say controllerA.

When delete button is clicked, I open a modal http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ which has Yes and No button. This modal is in a different controller say controllerB.

Q1. How can I get the value of id (row users want to delete) in controllerB? I am using a global var variable which I set in controllerA and get in controllerB but I don't think that is the correct way?

Q2. When users click Yes on modal (controllerB), how can I reload the page and display the refreshed grid (controllerA) - how can I get the value of dropdown and textbox in controllerB and how can I call controllerA's ng-click function in  controllerB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1:  Check out [this page for an example](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) on how to pass information to a modal dialog.  Basically you need to specify the **resolve** property when calling $modal.open.

Q2:  See the example again.  In ControllerA, you can call     **modalInstance.result.then(...)** and provide a function which will get called when the model dialog is dismissed.  Inside that function, you can make whatever web service call you wish, and when the web service call returns, your success function can update your $scope array variable which populates the data grid.

Answer (score 2):

Use an AngularJS **factory** or **service** to use methods across different controllers. You shouldn't be using global variables, you can look into using **$rootScope** to make things available in a broader scope.

Documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services & https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

One method to reload the page would be to call a re-render function on the ng-click from the controller so that it makes a call to the server for the most updated information (if you don't already have function/method that initially renders the page, otherwise call that in the ng-click again to re-render), that way you are executing multiple functions on the click, including the re-render.